# How does the ‘translate(self)’ work?

Tags: python

```
class Keeper(object):

    def __init__(self, keep):
        self.keep = sets.Set(map(ord, keep))

    def __getitem__(self, n):
        if n not in self.keep:
            return None
        return unichr(n)

    def __call__(self, s):
        return unicode(s).translate(self)

makefilter = Keeper

if __name__ == '__main__':
    just_vowels = makefilter('aeiouy')

    print just_vowels(u'four score and seven years ago')
```

It will emit “ouoeaeeyeaao”.

I know that the ‘translate’ function should recive a table  parameter which is created by string.maketrans().

But why the ‘self’ is passed in the translate function.

And how  does it call the __getitem__ function?

Comment: Put a `print n` in the `__getitem__` method and look what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Before we come to your snippet, let me explain when `__getitem__` is invoke:**

This is what `__getitem__` says:

**`__getitem__: object.__getitem__(self, key)`** is called to implement evaluation of **self[key]**.

For sequence types, the accepted keys should be integers and slice objects. Note that the special interpretation of negative indexes (if the class wishes to emulate a sequence type) is up to the `__getitem__()` method. If key is of an inappropriate type, `TypeError` may be raised; if of a value outside the set of indexes for the sequence (after any special interpretation of negative values), `IndexError` should be raised. For mapping types, if key is missing (not in the container), `KeyError` should be raised.

so, lets see the following snippet:

```
class Keeper(object):
    def __init__(self, keep):
        self.keep = set(map(ord, keep))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    just_vowels = Keeper('aeiouy')
    print just_vowels[1]
```

Output : is an error saying `does not support indexing` because there is no `__getitem__` method defined.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tran.py", line 15, in <module>
   print just_vowels[1]
TypeError: 'Keeper' object does not support indexing
```

Now lets change the snippet and adding `__getitem__` to allow object indexing:

```
class Keeper(object):
    def __init__(self, keep):
        self.keep = set(map(ord, keep))

    def __getitem__(self, n):
        if n in self.keep:
            return unichr(n)
        else:
            return 'Not Found in %s' % self.keep

if __name__ == '__main__':
    just_vowels = Keeper('aeiouy')
    for i in range(97,103):
        print just_vowels[i]
```

Output:

```
a
Not Found in set([97, 101, 105, 111, 117, 121])
Not Found in set([97, 101, 105, 111, 117, 121])
Not Found in set([97, 101, 105, 111, 117, 121])
e
Not Found in set([97, 101, 105, 111, 117, 121])
```

So, finally lets come to your snippet, when we use self as mapping table ie. dictionary. By default it will called `__getitem__` method to allow indexing and which numbers are in the range `[97, 101, 105, 111, 117, 121]`. So, if the number or `ord` value is not in the set, it just return None which means removing from your unicode string.

Here are some of the built-in python object which support numerical indexing:

```
>>> '__getitem__' in dir(dict)
True
>>> '__getitem__' in dir(list)
True
>>> '__getitem__' in dir(set)
False
>>> '__getitem__' in dir(tuple)
True
>>> '__getitem__' in dir(string)
False
>>>
```

Example on set indexing:

```
>>> s
set([1, 2])
>>> s[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
>>>
```

Let me explain the unicode translate part, I hope you already knew it but for some one who doesn't.

This is what `unicode.translate` says:

```
>>> help(unicode.translate)
Help on method_descriptor:

translate(...)
    S.translate(table) -> unicode
    Return a copy of the string S, where all characters have been mapped
    through the given translation table, which must be a mapping of
    Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals, Unicode strings or None.
    Unmapped characters are left untouched. Characters mapped to None
    are deleted.
>>
```

**Which requires a `table` could be dictionary i.e mapping of Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals, Unicode strings or None.**

Lets take an example: of removing punctuation from unicode string:

```
>>> uni_string = unicode('String with PUnctu@tion!."##')
>>> uni_string
u'String with PUnctu@tion!."##'
>>>
```

Lets create a mapping dictionary for punctuation to None:

```
>>> punc = '!"#$.'
>>> punc_map = {ord(x):None for x in punc }
>>> punc_map
{33: None, 34: None, 35: None, 36: None, 46: None}
>>>
```

Lets use this `punc_map` to translate a unicode string to remove punctuation:

```
>>> uni_string
u'String with PUnctu@tion!."##'
>>> uni_string.translate(punc_map)
u'String with PUnctu@tion'
>>>
```